# Finding path with specific length in weighted graph

Tags: routes

Given a weighted, cyclic, directed graph and two nodes I am looking for a connecting path which total weight comes as near as possible to a specific value which is greater than the shortest path.
Example in a real world scenario: Find a route from Washington D.C. to New York City which is 400 miles long, despite the shortest path is ~230 miles.
All my considerations so far failed for one of the following reasons:

- Most routing algorithms like Dijkstra are not working in this case because there is nothing to minimize or maximize (the divergence of given weight to path weight should be minimized, but you need the finished path to calculate it)
- DFS and BFS can be used to find a path with a specific number of hops (edges), but it doesn't consider weighted edges